# Why is it necessary to write Object=Object in Component to get Object.keys in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

In my Angular template I need the key count of an Object. I was writing `{{ Object.keys(myObj).length }}` in the template file. But it throws an error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined`.

Then from the internet I got a suggestion, so I wrote `Object = Object` in my component and it worked.

1. I don't understand what the philosophy behind this is.
2. How do other expressions and statements in curly braces work in an Angular template?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The template expression context is usually limited to the component instance itself. So when you interpolate a variable inside `{{}}` it will essentially look for a matching property of the underlying component instance or a template reference variable.

When you do `Object = Object` in a component, you are actually creating a property `Object` of the component which refers to the global `Object` which the component has a reference to.

But the same is not possible inside a template expression, it does not have any access to global properties except `undefined`.

This part of the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-context) explains this:

> Template expressions cannot refer to anything in the global namespace,
>   except undefined. They can't refer to window or document.
>   Additionally, they can't call console.log() or Math.max() and they are
>   restricted to referencing members of the expression context.

Comment: it's a kind of disadvantage that Global namespace isn't accessible. I had a hunch that template's context must be limited to component.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you render in the templates should be part of the coponent, this really helps with the encapsulation, helping to prevent future errors, unexpected behaviors and makes debug tasks easier
On the other hand a little more out of the subject, avoid using methods inside {{}} since they act as impure pipes and run a few times with each user interaction with the DOM, it is better that you save the result of the function, or method in a property in the component.ts and that property is the one that you show